# Route in Laravel without changing directory

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I have a route defined as follows:

```
Route::get('products/{name}', function($name) {
    return View::make('product')->with('name', $name);
});
```

The problem is that when this route is used, the current directory is changed to `example.com/products/` which is horrendous, as that completely breaks the links (an image that pointed to `images/nameOfImage.png` now points to `products/images/nameOfImage.png`, which doesn't exist).

How can I prevent this?

Comment: How do you use image link, with `asset` ?

Comment: It's just a straight href to the images folder in the public directory

Comment: Are you using blade ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is something else (It's because of relative `URL`), just try this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/nameOfImage.png') }}" />
```

Instead of directly using `<img src="images/nameOfImage.png" />`

Comment: Hmm, so that could work. The thing is that I have a lot of different files with probably hundreds of resources already linked directly. It would be much easier if there were another way to fix this

Comment: `<base href="http://www.your_root.com/">`, [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) as well.

Comment: Welcome but it's better if you can avoid base, check other `SO` answer (The link is given in previous comment).